# Ways of saying "to get into a relationship."

Tags: expressions

For love you have *to fall* in love. How about relationships?

I'm not an native English speaker so the only ones I can think of are: *to stumble* into a relationship and *to dive* into a relationship (which I believe aren't common at all).

Comment: We/they *began* a relationship is commonly used.

Comment: Actually, that's pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

You can "[fire up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fire_up)"/"ignite"/"kindle" a new relationship or re-ignite/re-kindle an old one.

For primarily non-romantic purposes, one can also  "establish a relationship."

Edited to add *"finding/found oneself/ourselves/themselves"* in a relationship:

> After years of friendship, we found ourselves in a relationship. The rest is history.

(Not to be confused with: "After years of marriage, we found ourselves in a relationship going nowhere"!)

Comment: +1 All good, but especially for *found*. And maybe even *floundered into* ...

Comment: @bib It's not at all surprising that you like 'found.' It was "inspired" solely by the notions conveyed by the first 4 items on your good list! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To [strike up](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/strike+up) can be appropriate in this situation: see 81c in the provided link. In this sense it means to begin, and is commonly used regarding acquaintance or relationship.

Answer (score 1):

- Started a relationship - "They felt so close they started a relationship"
- Less formally: Become an [item](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=item) - "They became an item almost as soon as they met"
- More formally: Entered a relationship (not normally used for romantic relationships!)

Answer (score 1):

You could

- slide
- ease
- tumble
- drift
- leap
- jump

into a relationship. And many more modes of movement, I am sure.

Comment: +1, especially for "slide/slid into..." (as well as for keeping the notion of movement in all your suggestions)

Comment: I suspect anyone who would tumble into a relationship is not someone you’d really want to be in a relationship with.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I have tumbled repeatedly, and often enjoyed it and often rued it.

Comment: Repeatedty? Well, that's just bragging!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm old and have often erred. Or maybe I'm just fantasizing.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the slightly more ambiguous "hook up".

"They hooked up." That means they entered into some sort of relationship. Depending on whom you are speaking with, this could mean various things, from going on a single date, to actually entering into a romantic relationship, to entering into a physical relationship (kissing, etc.). More importantly, it implies that they are more than just platonic friends, now.

Comment: I would never, ever use _hook up_ to mean entering into a _relationship_, i.e., a steady coupleship. “They hooked up” with no further context almost exclusively means that they had a one-night stand to me, or at least that they made out. It quite specifically connotes that there was _no_ date or relationship involved. [This is leaving aside more innocuous and irrelevant meanings of _hook up_, of course, as in “Let’s hook up for lunch and discuss the project” or “I hooked up with a friend while I was in Paris to chat about the old days”.]

Answer (score 1):

In common conversation, if you're talking about yourself, the most common usage I've heard is "enter".

```
I entered a relationship.
```